# How to auto-generate a .qrc file from a QML project for cmake

Tags: cmake, qml, qt5, qresource

Just putting this here for anyone else that needs this info. So they don't spend time on it needlessly.

I was trying to build my QtQuick project using Cmake and ROS2 but had the hardest time trying to figure out how to add custom modules and other files from an existing QML project to the CMakeLists of my ROS2 package. I knew from QT's [CMake template instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html) that I needed to put these files into a `.qrc` file. But it wasn't feasible to go through each file in the QML project and add them manually to a resource file, so I needed a way to auto-generate it.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to generate a `.qrc` file from your QML project you:

- First need to follow the steps [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-converting-ui-projects.html) to convert it to a QtQuick application
- Then build the application project
- Once that's done a resource file will be generated in the build folder
- At this point you can copy and paste that file into your main project (I suggest you rename the file as well)

Now you're all set to add this new `.qrc` to your CMakeLists.txt